# Auto set input values

Tags: jquery

Somewhat a simple question, but i can't get it working.

I want to make a simple checkup to see if the browser supports the placeholder attribute. If they don't i want to set the values if the input fields with jquery.

I'm testing it on firefox now, but can't get it working. I don't get any alert field..

This is what i got and what doesn't work...

```
jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val){
 if(i=="mozilla" && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,3)=="1.9"){
  $("input").each(function() {
   alert(this.id);
  });
 }
});
```

Tried this as well without a result

```
jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val){
 if(i=="mozilla" && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,3)=="1.9"){
  var $inputs = $("form :input");
  $inputs.each(function(el) {
   alert(el.id);
  });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ($.browser['opera']) {
   var $inputs = $("form input").each(function() {
     $(this).val('opera');
   }
} else if ($.browser['mozilla']) {
   var $inputs = $("form input").each(function() {
     $(this).val('mozilla');
   }
}
```

**Update**

```
var ids = $.map($("form input"), function(elem, i) {
   return $(this).attr('id');
});
alert('all ids = ' + ids.join(','));
```

Comment: It's not about the browser check, that works. I just want to get the values of the id attribute of the input elements. :)